# How to get the last auto-inserted SQL timestamp

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with a `TIMESTAMP` column that uses the `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` as its default-value. After I performed an `INSERT` on this table in PHP (not specifying the value for the timestamp-column, thus the current_timestamp gets used), I want to know the timestamp that got inserted, much like [mysqli::$insert_id](http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.insert-id.php) does it with the primary key.

I searched the [PHP documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/de/class.mysqli.php), but didnt find anything.

Is there an easy way to do this **without** creating an additional query?

Comment: tried last inserted row?

Comment: @RakeshSharma where do i get it? I could not find it in the class

Comment: not possible without query

Comment: If you can modify your script to insert the timestamp as `date('Y-m-d H:i:s')`, and keep that value stored in PHP for use/reference later. This will override the `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` value that you've set up.

Comment: @Noah That is exactly what i thought to do if the answer to the question is no, as it seems to be.

Comment: I'm more perplexed as to why you can't query the information

Comment: @Noah I can, I just do not want to create unnecessary queries

Comment: up-voted with question, why would some down-vote this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## No.

You want analogy to the `LAST_INSERT_ID`, but for ID it makes sense, since there's no other way for you to get it. For TIMESTAMP however, it doesn't make too much sense, since you already know the ID (whether it was explicit or automatic), so you can query it from the table yourself. You *can* and you *have to* if you want to know the TIMESTAMP.

EDIT: But, if you want to save the select query, you can make a trick:

```
select now()
insert ...
select now()
```

If the two timestamps are equal (which will be in 90% cases), you can assume that the updated timestamp is the same. Otherwise you have to perform the select query. But this is way too complicated to be practical :-)

Comment: Thanks. I think I will move to controlling the timestamp from php instead of using the sql default, as it creates less requests and is actually easier to read.

Comment: @LionC yes, I think this is a best solution for you!